# correct way to call a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm somewhat new with JavaScript & am basing a tic-tac-toe game off this semi-tutorial: https://blog.vivekpanyam.com/how-to-build-an-ai-that-wins-the-basics-of-minimax-search/ ). While trying to see if a computer vs computer method works in there (will make it delay after it works so it’s not a 10millisecond game), I ran into some snags. Prob easy fixes if I knew what was going on more..

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/afbn3on6/3/

// This code targets the html & is inside $(document).ready(function()

```
if($(".cvc").hasClass('player_mode')){
    return makeMove();
}
```

// This code starts the game (the many other functions it calls are on the jsfiddle)

```
function makeMove() {
  board = minimaxMove(board);
  console.log(numNodes);
  $(".cvc").hasClass('player_mode') ? myMove = true : myMove = false;
  updateMove();
}
```

// updateMove() calls updateButtons() which is where "x" & "o" are assigned

```
function updateButtons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      $("#c" + i + "" + j).text(board[i][j] == false ? "x" : board[i][j] == true ? "o" : "");
    }
  }
}
```

I call the function from inside `$(document).ready(function()` so why wouldn't it auto-play when clicked?

The computer vs computer (cvc) works, but you have to click 1st (which isn't the computer's move) & then the computer goes 3x in a row & wins: doesn't change back & forth “x” to “o” to "x", etc

Any help / pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: `maybe it should return makeMove();` - why? is that function defined somewhere?

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself***

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to StackOverflow & didn't know how much to copy, that's why I linked to the JSFiddle.  Hopefully the updated post is more clear?